# Problems with ybar stacked plot converted to xbar stacked

Tags: pgfplots

I had a group of two `ybar stacked` plots which worked quite well, but I needed to convert it to a similar configuration of two `xbar stacked` plots. It is the running time and memory consumption of a set of software tools over different sets of input data.

So I swapped all the vertical/horizontal and x/y pairs I could find, and transposed the tables, but the result is wrong: it kinda seem to work but only the first seven rows are shown, with huge spacing between them.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Reds-7}

\newcommand\tools%
  {first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh}

\pgfplotstableread{time-benchmarks.txt}\timedata
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=group]{\timedata}{\timedata}

\pgfplotstableread{memory-benchmarks.txt}\memorydata
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=group]{\memorydata}{\memorydata}

\NewDocumentCommand\datapoints{sm}{
  \foreach \tool in \tools {

    \addplot table[y expr=\coordindex, x={\tool}] {#2};

    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
      \expandafter\addlegendentry\expandafter{\tool}
    }{}
  }
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    % group size and spacing
    group style={
      group size=2 by 1,
      y descriptions at=edge left,
      horizontal sep=2ex
    },
    % Stacked bar plot
    xbar stacked,
    % Size and spacing
    height=16cm,
    width=6cm,
    /pgf/bar width=1.8ex,
    enlarge y limits=0.02,
    enlarge x limits=0,
    % Bar style
    cycle list name=Reds-7,
    every axis plot/.append style={fill},
    axis line style={
      draw=none
    },
    % Axis ticks and descriptions
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\memorydata}{group},
    tick label style={
      font=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
      %rotate=-90
    },
    tick style={
      draw=none
    },
    % Legend
    legend style={
      legend columns=4,
      anchor=west,
      at={(0,-1cm)},
      draw=none,
      font=\ttfamily,
      /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=1em}
    }
  ]

  \nextgroupplot
    \datapoints*{\timedata}

  \nextgroupplot
    \datapoints{\memorydata}
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image: output]

What am i doing wrong?

Here I pasted the two example data files to be saved as `time-benchmarks.txt` and `memory-benchmarks.txt`. The first:

```
group  first        second       third        fourth       fifth        sixth        seventh
set01  0.004111     0.009152     0.045724     0.005717     0.021879     0.002881     0.002945
set02  0.008477     0.211507     0.053515     0.007908     990.668120   249.920847   217.070817
set03  0.004044     0.008985     0.044974     0.005878     0.018385     0.002912     0.002863
set04  2.075985     1306.278378  7.665451     1760.381948  1104.620070  1143.079517  1226.006896
set05  1.897231     1368.994888  4.899534     1773.628201  1016.592014  1186.307643  1245.391219
set06  2.137058     1317.487465  9.685547     1800.055000  1134.715376  1178.582506  1167.383633
set07  4.266404     1319.283929  19.259639    1800.048824  1178.716000  1403.177228  1380.575205
set08  3.307151     1425.309175  0.118215     1800.057647  920.797998   1434.119709  1694.171620
set09  0.818796     1177.283560  20.773745    1800.053529  1255.335457  1104.185453  1178.818483
set10  1.627116     1179.517775  41.466340    1800.051176  1273.744990  1425.870249  1588.298746
set11  7.371055     1311.447020  0.096659     1800.055294  1138.917764  1407.002186  1699.648235
set12  0.009644     547.394445   0.056474     1129.883679  1133.682485  1136.452059  1094.560324
set13  0.011048     1361.575559  1200.070602  1666.749689  1200.091553  1200.054252  1200.086195
set14  1317.986718  1305.776547  1308.976817  1700.055894  904.945922   1500.754501  1408.624460
set15  0.036568     3.715888     1.987156     1660.551121  1496.753129  794.032976   347.069509
set16  0.129680     29.559169    9.330906     984.837292   1800.050316  635.171478   635.082265
set17  0.007284     0.110542     0.063316     1139.871041  0.061051     0.045342     106.208491
set18  0.016777     0.531091     0.056427     591.504852   0.649931     445.751227   591.448025
set19  419.720425   0.141559     562.409300   1094.588491  785.076416   304.396500   225.651039
set20  380.819979   0.067163     30.309266    709.116910   789.208049   354.451747   247.732775
```

And the second:

```
group  first          second         third          fourth         fifth          sixth          seventh
set01  0.000000       0.000000       33936.000000   0.000000       11311.600000   0.000000       0.000000
set02  34564.444444   69238.777778   50275.555556   0.000000       349995.222222  106615.888889  78532.333333
set03  0.000000       0.000000       22624.000000   0.000000       4524.640000    0.000000       0.000000
set04  67432.352941   196224.588235  146219.794118  116608.411765  414637.647059  407371.882353  100848.529412
set05  69782.941176   207916.000000  150164.882353  118411.882353  393563.000000  414367.529412  101667.823529
set06  67878.470588   258053.764706  203845.058824  117483.764706  415750.588235  415770.000000  101679.294118
set07  135756.941176  252071.294118  321186.588235  117485.411765  416749.176471  471732.235294  112459.058824
set08  143374.823529  154586.117647  106465.882353  120354.823529  376624.941176  458422.823529  112413.176471
set09  63573.176471   219101.294118  184737.647059  115778.000000  447701.764706  404212.823529  98374.705882
set10  127146.352941  200706.117647  302934.117647  115816.705882  460615.764706  471448.705882  112311.058824
set11  133180.705882  146871.058824  99811.764706   118712.705882  427384.000000  456427.058824  119488.470588
set12  37706.666667   73347.555556   41896.296296   77273.777778   332006.222222  341931.555556  79679.111111
set13  4189.629630    167544.296296  392738.518519  168429.629630  368290.518519  363526.370370  97891.407407
set14  300971.777778  184636.444444  422871.333333  116328.444444  331805.777778  447640.444444  175552.000000
set15  40440.400000   92626.780000   119374.080000  161314.320000  517330.040000  482399.760000  116181.390000
set16  39889.684211   117088.715789  248812.505263  92251.326316   528166.463158  237964.400000  78447.157895
set17  8484.000000    56599.633333   56128.300000   128058.716667  50902.200000   9520.183333    15131.166667
set18  19392.000000   105585.257143  49423.885714   50515.514286   110895.885714  176454.257143  38508.000000
set19  305131.789474  62638.842105   132970.000000  273445.421053  360182.631579  258869.894737  213830.315789
set20  308996.421053  47629.473684   86328.421053   265038.842105  361456.736842  268400.000000  217749.368421
```

Comment: I’ve already swapped them, the height is greater than the width, it should be ok for a vertical thing, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you did was right, instead of transposing the data tables. By deleting these two lines you will get the desired result.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
    \begin{filecontents*}{time-benchmarks.txt}
        group  first        second       third        fourth       fifth        sixth        seventh
        set01  0.004111     0.009152     0.045724     0.005717     0.021879     0.002881     0.002945
        set02  0.008477     0.211507     0.053515     0.007908     990.668120   249.920847   217.070817
        set03  0.004044     0.008985     0.044974     0.005878     0.018385     0.002912     0.002863
        set04  2.075985     1306.278378  7.665451     1760.381948  1104.620070  1143.079517  1226.006896
        set05  1.897231     1368.994888  4.899534     1773.628201  1016.592014  1186.307643  1245.391219
        set06  2.137058     1317.487465  9.685547     1800.055000  1134.715376  1178.582506  1167.383633
        set07  4.266404     1319.283929  19.259639    1800.048824  1178.716000  1403.177228  1380.575205
        set08  3.307151     1425.309175  0.118215     1800.057647  920.797998   1434.119709  1694.171620
        set09  0.818796     1177.283560  20.773745    1800.053529  1255.335457  1104.185453  1178.818483
        set10  1.627116     1179.517775  41.466340    1800.051176  1273.744990  1425.870249  1588.298746
        set11  7.371055     1311.447020  0.096659     1800.055294  1138.917764  1407.002186  1699.648235
        set12  0.009644     547.394445   0.056474     1129.883679  1133.682485  1136.452059  1094.560324
        set13  0.011048     1361.575559  1200.070602  1666.749689  1200.091553  1200.054252  1200.086195
        set14  1317.986718  1305.776547  1308.976817  1700.055894  904.945922   1500.754501  1408.624460
        set15  0.036568     3.715888     1.987156     1660.551121  1496.753129  794.032976   347.069509
        set16  0.129680     29.559169    9.330906     984.837292   1800.050316  635.171478   635.082265
        set17  0.007284     0.110542     0.063316     1139.871041  0.061051     0.045342     106.208491
        set18  0.016777     0.531091     0.056427     591.504852   0.649931     445.751227   591.448025
        set19  419.720425   0.141559     562.409300   1094.588491  785.076416   304.396500   225.651039
        set20  380.819979   0.067163     30.309266    709.116910   789.208049   354.451747   247.732775
    \end{filecontents*}
    \begin{filecontents*}{memory-benchmarks.txt}
        group  first          second         third          fourth         fifth          sixth          seventh
        set01  0.000000       0.000000       33936.000000   0.000000       11311.600000   0.000000       0.000000
        set02  34564.444444   69238.777778   50275.555556   0.000000       349995.222222  106615.888889  78532.333333
        set03  0.000000       0.000000       22624.000000   0.000000       4524.640000    0.000000       0.000000
        set04  67432.352941   196224.588235  146219.794118  116608.411765  414637.647059  407371.882353  100848.529412
        set05  69782.941176   207916.000000  150164.882353  118411.882353  393563.000000  414367.529412  101667.823529
        set06  67878.470588   258053.764706  203845.058824  117483.764706  415750.588235  415770.000000  101679.294118
        set07  135756.941176  252071.294118  321186.588235  117485.411765  416749.176471  471732.235294  112459.058824
        set08  143374.823529  154586.117647  106465.882353  120354.823529  376624.941176  458422.823529  112413.176471
        set09  63573.176471   219101.294118  184737.647059  115778.000000  447701.764706  404212.823529  98374.705882
        set10  127146.352941  200706.117647  302934.117647  115816.705882  460615.764706  471448.705882  112311.058824
        set11  133180.705882  146871.058824  99811.764706   118712.705882  427384.000000  456427.058824  119488.470588
        set12  37706.666667   73347.555556   41896.296296   77273.777778   332006.222222  341931.555556  79679.111111
        set13  4189.629630    167544.296296  392738.518519  168429.629630  368290.518519  363526.370370  97891.407407
        set14  300971.777778  184636.444444  422871.333333  116328.444444  331805.777778  447640.444444  175552.000000
        set15  40440.400000   92626.780000   119374.080000  161314.320000  517330.040000  482399.760000  116181.390000
        set16  39889.684211   117088.715789  248812.505263  92251.326316   528166.463158  237964.400000  78447.157895
        set17  8484.000000    56599.633333   56128.300000   128058.716667  50902.200000   9520.183333    15131.166667
        set18  19392.000000   105585.257143  49423.885714   50515.514286   110895.885714  176454.257143  38508.000000
        set19  305131.789474  62638.842105   132970.000000  273445.421053  360182.631579  258869.894737  213830.315789
        set20  308996.421053  47629.473684   86328.421053   265038.842105  361456.736842  268400.000000  217749.368421
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        colorbrewer,
        groupplots,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.13,
        cycle list/Reds-7,
    }
    \newcommand\tools%
      {first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh}

    \pgfplotstableread{time-benchmarks.txt}{\timedata}
    \pgfplotstableread{memory-benchmarks.txt}{\memorydata}

    \NewDocumentCommand\datapoints{sm}{
        \foreach \tool in \tools {
            \addplot table [y expr=\coordindex,x={\tool}] {#2};

            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
                \expandafter\addlegendentry\expandafter{\tool}
            }{}
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        % group size and spacing
        group style={
            group size=2 by 1,
            y descriptions at=edge left,
            horizontal sep=2ex,
        },
        % Stacked bar plot
        xbar stacked,
        % Size and spacing
        height=9cm,
        width=6cm,
        /pgf/bar width=1.8ex,
        enlarge y limits=0.02,
        enlarge x limits=0,
        % Bar style
        cycle list name=Reds-7,
        every axis plot/.append style={
            fill,
        },
        axis line style={
            draw=none,
        },
        % Axis ticks and descriptions
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=data,
        yticklabels from table={\memorydata}{group},
        tick label style={
            font=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
            %rotate=-90,
        },
        tick style={
            draw=none,
        },
        % Legend
        legend style={
            legend columns=4,
            anchor=west,
            at={(0,-1cm)},
            draw=none,
            font=\ttfamily,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={
                column sep=1em,
            },
        },
    ]

    \nextgroupplot
        \datapoints*{\timedata}
    \nextgroupplot
        \datapoints{\memorydata}

    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Wow, so simple XD